# Error while creating a function thet returns array of strings in matlab?

Tags: matlab

**I am learning MATLAB and was trying to code the following.**
Write a function called “buildrandomstrings” that will receive as input an integer n.Now If n is +ve: it will create and return a cell array with strings of random characters of increasing lengths, from 1 to n. Each string will be constituted by the previous random string plus an extra random character.

Now my code-

```
function buildrandomstrings = buildrandomstrings(inchar, posint)
% Creates a cell array with strings of increasing
% lengths, from 1:n, starting with inchar
% Format of call: buildstr(input char, n)
% Returns cell array with n strings

buildrandomstrings= cell(1, posint);
inchar = char(inchar-1);

strin = '';

for i = 1:posint
    strin = strcat(strin, char(inchar+i));
    buildrandomstrings{i} = strin;
end
end
```

But I am getting the following error which makes no sense to me. Even though I have looked everywhere.

```
buildrandomstrings(4)
```

> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in buildrandomstrings (line 7)
>
> buildrandomstrings= cell(1, posint);

When I do ctrl+click I get the following.

> Creates a cell array with strings of increasing   lengths, from 1:n,
>   starting with inchar   Format of call: buildstr(input char, n)
>   Returns cell array with n strings

Comment: @SardarUsama I am not running it I am calling the function itself but its not working.

Comment: @SardarUsama I  I missed the the quote on char for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you run `buildrandomstrings(4)`. However, you need to provide two arguments as defined by your function `function buildrandomstrings = buildrandomstrings(inchar, posint)`.

Try:

```
buildrandomstrings('a', 4)
```

Output:

```
ans =
  1×4 cell array
    {'a'}    {'ab'}    {'abc'}    {'abcd'}
```

Comment: No problem. Note, your way of generating a random string `char(inchar+i)` is not perfect. Consider using `randi()`:)

Comment: To get a string that is the previous string minus the last character, you can use slicing. For example, buildrandomstrings{i-1} = buildrandomstrings{i}(1:end-1).